# How can a hash have a fixed length?

Tags: encryption, hash, algorithm-design

I am very new to cryptography, I apologize if my question is so basic.

I do not understand how a hash can have a fixed length, because you can have infinite inputs to a hash function. With a fixed length you would have limited possibilities of hash outputs. So a hash can have different messages with the exact same output?

Comment: It seems like you've asked and then abandoned this question. If one of the answers suffices then please accept one of them; otherwise please followup with a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we talked about a cryptographic hash function, we want them to process arbitrary length inputs and fixed outputs.

\begin{align}
H:&\{0,1\}^*\to \{0,1\}^\ell\\
m&\mapsto H(m)
\end{align}
where the $\ell$ is the size of the hash function.

Hash functions based on [Merkle–Damgård construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction)<sup>†</sup> use a compression function $f$ to achieve the fixed size output;

1. The message $M$ is padded and divided into $\ell$ length blocks $M_1,\ldots,M_n$
2. $H_0$ is set to initial values;
3. From $1$ to $n$ $$H_i = f(H_{i-1},M_i)$$
4. Output $H(M) = H_n$

A changeable output size according to input size is hard to build and is not feasible for protocols. Building a hash function with a larger output then truncating is much safer as in [SHA-224](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/hash-functions) ( note: the parameters are different then SHA-256)

By the simple combinatorial argument, since the input space is much larger than the output space, the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) implies that there will be more than one input value maps to the **same hash value**. Indeed, with the arbitrary size of the input, there will be **numerous** inputs will hash the same value. As pointed in poncho's answer, we want collision-resistance for hash functions;

- If finding two inputs that hash to the same output $a$ and $b$ such that $H(a)= H(b)$, $a \neq b$ is hard then we have **collision resistance**.

Collision resistance considered an easier security goal to achieve, [Joux 2004](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2004/31520306/multicollisions.pdf). There is a generic attack by [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) that after $2^{\ell/2}$ hash calculations we expect a collision with 50%. To have resistance to generic birthday attacks, one has to use a hash function double size of the threat. As an example, the SHA-1 output size is 160-bit with 80-bit generic birthday attack it is [no longer recommended](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Hash-Functions/NIST-Policy-on-Hash-Functions) by NIST;

> SHA-1: Federal agencies should stop using SHA-1 for generating digital signatures, generating time stamps and for other applications that require collision resistance. Federal agencies may use SHA-1 for the following applications: verifying old digital signatures and time stamps, generating and verifying hash-based message authentication codes (HMACs), key derivation functions (KDFs), and random bit/number generation. Further guidance on the use of SHA-1 is provided in SP 800-131A.
>
> August 5, 2015

For other properties of hash functions, see [How do hashes really ensure uniqueness?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/63339/18298).

---

<sub><sup>†</sup> SHA-3 uses [Sponge function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponge_function).</sub>

Answer (score 8):

> So a hash can have different messages with the exact same output?

Yes; that's true of any function with inputs longer than the output.

What *collision resistance* of a hash function doesn't mean that there aren't two messages $X$ and $Y$ that hash to the same value; instead, it means that it's hard to find them.

Comment: I like your very short take on this answer. I'd reword slightly the part about inputs/outputs, maybe along the line of "number of possible inputs is bigger than number of possible outputs" (surjective function? not sure).

Comment: @domen there's already the name pigeon hole principle for this concept.

Comment: @Natanael, I know. I agree, it would make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

To **understand the mechanism**, you could refer to the one of the simplest and **dumb** hashing method that everyone knows, the **arithmetic $modulo$ operation**.

> Different-length input numbers produce the same-length results through $mod$.

For example:

- if we want only $8$-bit output values, we choose $2^{8}$ as modulo divisor
- we could simply choose $4$ input numbers of different lengths ( 8, 16, 24, 32 bits), that will produce the **same output value** (*aka* $4$ **collisions**):

  - $(2^{32}-1) \equiv 255\ (\textrm{mod}\ 256) $
  - $(2^{24}-1) \equiv 255\ (\textrm{mod}\ 256) $
  - $(2^{16}-1) \equiv 255\ (\textrm{mod}\ 256) $
  - $(2^{8}-1) \equiv 255\ (\textrm{mod}\ 256) $
- Obviously for cryptographic hash like **SHA256/512** it's quite hard to find 2 inputs that produce the same output.
- take also a look to the [pigeon's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)