# Please explain me why we require $2^m$ & $2^{\frac{m}{2}}$ random messages

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

Assume that a one-way Hash function is secure and the best way to attack it is by using the brute force attack. It produces an $m$-bit output. Finding a message that hashes to a given hash value would require hashing **$2^m$ random messages**. Finding two messages that hash to the same value would only require hashing **$2^{\frac{m}{2}}$ random messages.**

I know only about birthday paradox involving 23 people. How do I relate the birthday paradox with this attack?

Answer (score 8):

$2^m$ requirement is for the pre-image attack. You have to hash approximately  $2^m$ messages to find the message that has the same value you were looking for if the hash function has [pre-image resistance](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63340/18298).

In a collision attack, you are looking for two messages that have the same hash value.

If you look at Wikipedia Birthday Paradox at section [Cast as a collision problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Cast_as_a_collision_problem), it is also generalized for the arbitrary number of days not just for 365 days. The approximation is given by

$$n \approx \sqrt{2^m}$$ and we call it generic birthday attack.

Note that: if you find an attack which is faster than generic birthday attack like [SHA-1 attack](https://shattered.io/) you will be famous.